# How to display all Surveys from a site onto a page in a table or list format?

Tags: list, web-part, application-pages, survey

I am on SharePoint 2013 and I have created a couple of surveys (e.g. Survey 1, Survey 2, Survey X) on one of my sites. Now I want to create a page that will display all of these surveys in a table like format. It would look something like this:

[image]

I tried doing this with CQWP and it doesn't work, because I need to get the Surveys themselves, not the items within it. I'm looking to do this with OOTB functionality, no programming. I am OK with creating ItemStyles or other needed styling, just really avoiding code.
Is this possible using OOTB? For example, a Content Search or something?

Comment: Do you need it to dynamically update as you add new surveys, or are you OK with manually adding items to the list?

Comment: Ideally, I want it to automatically update whenever a new Survey is added to the site. If that is not really possible OOTB though, I think just creating a custom list with links to the actual surveys will be the approach to be done. My problem with that is that there is an additional step to creating a new list item whenever a new Survey is being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it via the Content Search Web Part. I created an Advanced Query and put in the following:

```
contentclass:STS_List_Survey filename:overview.aspx
```

What it does is just basically return the base view of all the Survey List I have on my Site Collection. Afterwards, I just needed to modify the search results style template so that I have what I need. I used this as reference: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_quick_reads/2013/08/01/sharepoint-2013-customize-display-template-for-content-by-search-web-part-cswp-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way OOTB to dynamically display a list of surveys.  There might be a way to grab them programatically, but you ruled out that approach.

I would use the list approach - have a list of hyperlinks to your surveys and display a web part of that list on your page.  It does add a step to your survey creation, but you can then put a sort on them by age, priority, etc.

Good luck!